# iPhone image memory leak

Tags: iphone, image, memory-leaks

We have a code like this

```
NSData* imageData;
UIImage* imageForData;
UIImageView* imageView;

NSData* imageData;
UIImage* imageForData;
UIImageView* imageView;
    CellWithId *  cell = [[CellWithId alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = 5;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size.height = 43;
frame.size.width = 52;

if ([[planDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"]!=[NSNull null]) {
    imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[planDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"]]];
    imageForData = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageForData];
    imageView.frame = frame;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageData release];
    [imageForData release];

}NSData* imageData;
UIImage* imageForData;
UIImageView* imageView;
//CellWithId *cell = (CellWithId*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
// if (cell == nil) {
CellWithId *  cell = [[CellWithId alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//}

CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = 5;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size.height = 43;
frame.size.width = 52;

if ([[planDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"]!=[NSNull null]) {
    imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[planDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"]]];
    imageForData = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageForData];
    imageView.frame = frame;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageData release];
    [imageForData release];

}else {
    //imageForData = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Plans-Default-image.jpg"];
    imageForData = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Plans-Default-image" ofType:@"jpg"]];

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageForData];
    imageView.frame = frame;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
}

[imageView release];
```

I dont know what is the problem but imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[planDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"]]]; is a place which always shows memory leaks. Please help me to debug this issue.

Comment: What object does it say is being leaked?

Comment: Did you paste your code twice or is this how your code actually looks?

Answer (score 1):

You allocate two `CellWithId`and never release it. It looks as though you do not properly implement this method. The cell returned in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

should be autoreleased:

```
CellWithId *  cell = [[[CellWithId alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
// ...
return (UITableViewCell *)cell;
```

Also you should use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier`properly to have decent performance.